# Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException - <error: an exception of type: {System.NullReferenceException} occurred> string

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle10g, c#-2.0

I need your help to resolve this error happens when you try to open the oracle connection to the database. `Connection.Open ();`

ConnectionString value:

```
"Data Source=dbora1;Max Pool Size=50;Min Pool Size=1;Connection Lifetime=120;Enlist=true;User Id=slu;Password=slu_4d332;"   string
```

The exception is null and strack trace is as follows:

```
StackTrace  "   
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle.OracleDatabase.OpenConnection() in c:\\v\\enterpriselibrary\\front_end\\fuentes\\data\\oracle\\oracledatabase.cs:line 444" string
```

They also left an [image of the quickview of the variable that captured the exepcion.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwzv0.jpg)

Here is the complete code for initialization of the connection to the database:

```
protected override IDbConnection OpenConnection()
        {
            OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection)GetConnection();
            try
            {
                //Test the connection context mark.
                if ( connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed )
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                this.instrumentation.ConnectionOpened(ConnectionStringNoCredentials);
                return connection;
            }

            catch (System.ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                connection = (OracleConnection)GetConnection( true );

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    return connection;
                }
                catch
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    throw;
                }
            }
            catch(System.InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                // Log in eventviewer
                LogConnectionPoolTimeOutEvent(e);

                connection.Close();
                this.instrumentation.ConnectionFailed(ConnectionStringNoCredentials);
                throw;

            }
            catch (System.OutOfMemoryException)
            {
                connection.Close();
                this.instrumentation.ConnectionFailed(ConnectionStringNoCredentials);
                throw;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                connection.Close();
                this.instrumentation.ConnectionFailed(ConnectionStringNoCredentials);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

And the method code GetConnection () is:

```
public override IDbConnection GetConnection()
{
    return GetConnection( false );
}

protected IDbConnection GetConnection( bool renew )
{
    IDictionary connectionHolder;
    OracleConnection tempConn;
    //Test the connection context mark.
    if ( ConnectionContext.CachedConnectionContext )
    {//If the mark is in the callcontext
        //Get the connection holder
        connectionHolder = CallContext.GetData(ConnectionContext.CALLCONTEXTKEY) as IDictionary;
        //If the connection holder does not exists
        if ( connectionHolder == null )
        {
            //create a conection holder
            connectionHolder = new Hashtable();
            //create the initial connection
            tempConn = new OracleConnection(base.ConnectionString);
            //add the connection to the holder
            connectionHolder.Add(base.ConnectionString, tempConn);
            //save the holder in the call context
            CallContext.SetData(ConnectionContext.CALLCONTEXTKEY, connectionHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            //get the connection from the holder
            tempConn = connectionHolder[base.ConnectionString] as OracleConnection;
            if ( tempConn == null )
            { //if the connection was not in the holder
                //create a new connection
                tempConn = new OracleConnection(base.ConnectionString);
                //add the connection to the holder
                connectionHolder.Add(base.ConnectionString, tempConn);
            }
            else
            { //if the connection exists
                if ( renew )
                { //if should renew the connection

                    //TODO:Delete
                    HealthModel.Trace.TraceToken token = HealthModel.Trace.TraceHelper.Start( "+++++++ R e n e w", "", "", 0 );


                    //closes the connection
                    tempConn.Close();
                    //create a new connection
                    tempConn = new OracleConnection(base.ConnectionString);
                    //add the connection to the holder
                    connectionHolder[base.ConnectionString] = tempConn;

                    //TODO:Delete
                    HealthModel.Trace.TraceHelper.End( token );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {//if the mark was not in the call context
        //create a connection
        tempConn = new OracleConnection(base.ConnectionString);
    }
    return tempConn;
}
```

I hope you can help me.
regards
Juan Pablo.

Comment: Can you please show the full code where you initialize and open the connection?

Comment: I just added the requested code. Thank you very much Wernfried!

Comment: What is `GetConnection()`? I assume it returns `null` which cause the error.

Comment: I just added the code of GetConnection so you can review it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the `IDbConnection` Interface?

Simply try this:

```
string connectString = "Data Source=dbora1;Max Pool Size=50;Min Pool Size=1;Connection Lifetime=120;Enlist=true;User Id=slu;Password=slu_4d332";

OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectString);
connection.Open();
```

Comment: I just change my code to not use the interface but the error persists. :(

Answer (score 0):

Werfried

I just change my code to not use the interface but the error persists.

```
    protected override IDbConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        string cs = "Data Source=dbora1;Max Pool Size=50;Min Pool Size=1;Connection Lifetime=120;Enlist=true;User Id=slu;Password=slu_4d332";;
        OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(cs);
        try{
        connection.Open();
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {                   
                ex.ToString();
            }

        return connection;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

[Deputy exception image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3bzX.jpg)
StackTrace:

```
StackTrace  "   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure)\r\n   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)\r\n   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()\r\n   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()\r\n   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle.OracleDatabase.OpenConnection() in c:\\v\\enterpriselibrary\\front_end\\fuentes\\data\\oracle\\oracledatabase.cs:line 441"    string
```

Thanks for your time